# How do I switch image and text back and forth in tapping the button?

Tags: android, kotlin

The first time I tap the button, both the image1 and text1 changed to image2 & text2. How do I change both the image and text back to 1st set the 2nd time I tap the button and change them to 2nd set the 3rd time I tap the button ?

Here is my current codes:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    fun eating(view: View?) {
        val afterEatingText:String="I am so full!!"
        displayMessage(afterEatingText)
        displayImage(R.drawable.after_cookie)
    }
    private fun displayMessage(message: String) {
        val afterEatingText = findViewById<View>(R.id.before_eating) as TextView
        afterEatingText.text = message
    }
    private fun displayImage(imagesource: Int){
        val afterEatingImage: ImageView = findViewById<View>(R.id.before_cookie) as ImageView
        afterEatingImage.setImageResource(imagesource)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: FYI, instead of putting `findViewById<View>(R.id.before_eating) as TextView` you can put just `findViewById<TextView>(R.id.before_eating)`. Same thing with your ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var isClick:Boolean=false
 var  afterEatingText :TextView?=null
 var afterEatingImage:ImageView?=null

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    afterEatingImage= findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.before_cookie)  // find your id you can also direct call with its ids in kotlin
    afterEatingText = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.before_eating)
}
fun eating(view: View?) {
  if(isClick){
     isClick=true
      // set your first image and text
  }else {
     isClick=false
    val afterEatingText:String="I am so full!!"
    displayMessage(afterEatingText)
    displayImage(R.drawable.after_cookie)
}}
private fun displayMessage(message: String) {
    afterEatingText.text = message
}
private fun displayImage(imagesource: Int){
    afterEatingImage.setImageResource(imagesource)
}
```

}

Comment: I copy your codes into mine and run it. I get red alert `Only safe(?.) or non-null asserted(!!.)calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type TextView?` with line numbers point to these 2 lines `afterEatingText.text = message`     &   `afterEatingImage.setImageResource(imagesource)` How to fix this?

Comment: Q(1): Does `isClick:Boolean=flase` mean when I has NOT tap the button? Q(2): Does `onCreate(){   afterEatingImage= findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.before_cookie) 
    afterEatingText = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.before_eating)  }`   shows the default status before the button is tapped?        Q(3):  Which specific line of code shows the 2nd time I tap the button, the images & texts switch back to default status?

Comment: ? is for handel null exception use textView?.text=""   isClick is check for setting 1 and 2 click when you click onfirst time its become true and the second time its become false